# Prove that the matrix $I_n - A$ is invertible

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with the property that $A^3 = O_n$, where $O_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ matrix which
has all the entries equal to $0$. Let $I_n$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Prove that the matrix $I_n - A$
is invertible, and indicate how you would obtain its inverse.

Comment: What is $I_n \to A$? How is the operation "$\to$" defined?

Comment: Hopefuly $I_n - A$ ?

Comment: yes, it will be matrix $I_n - A$

Answer (score 5):

I think that it should read $I_n -A$ instead of $I_n \rightarrow A$.

Observe that

$ I_n=I_n-A^3=(I_n-A)(A^2+A+I_n)$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean you are looking for the inverse of $I_n - A$.

> The answer is $I_n+A+A^2.$

as results from the development of

$$(I_n - A)(I_n+A+A^2)=I_n$$

due to the property $A^3=0_n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $|x|<1$, one has: $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^k.$$
Can you see how to adapt this to find the inverse of $I-A$, where $A$ is nilpotent?

Comment: I can't see how...in particular if we cannot decide what $\;|A|\;$ would mean wrt matrices as similar with that $\;|x|<1\;$ for real (or complex) $\;x\;$ . The only tagging here is matrices.

Comment: I am well aware that one need to equip the set of matrices with an operator norm to give sense to Neumann's series. However, my idea was just to suggest the OP doing formal manipulations, since here all the series are finite sums. This is the same idea when one wants to define the logarithm of an unipotent matrix.